# Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnitName) what does this argument refer to?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In [`Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnitName)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/index.html?javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html) what does the argument refer to?

JavaDoc just says

> persistenceUnitName - the name of the persistence unit

Which basically just repeats the argument name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A persistence unit is basically a bunch of entity classes grouped together with common configuration for the database connection and behaviour of the JPA implementation.

Classically, it was defined using a [`persistence.xml`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cfgdepds005.htm). In there you would give the persistence unit a name by an XML root tag like [`<persistence-unit name="OrderManagement5">`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cfgdepds005.htm#CIHGJEBF). This is the name referenced by the `String` argument of `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnitName)`.

With modern application frameworks and the default case of just one persistence unit in the application, all this gets configured automatically and the persistence unit name doesn't appear anywhere in your code anymore.